# In Visual Studio 2010, how do I stop new projects being added & built in every existing build configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a number of configurations setup in Visual Studio with a carefully crafted list of projects that each one should build.

When I create a new project in the solution it gets selected for building automatically in every existing build configuration.

Is there an option to stop this occurring?

Answer (score 0):

In the solution configuration manager you can unselect build (and deploy) of individual projects for different build configurations.

Right click on solution, select properties, Configuration Properties.

Or Build | Configuration Manager

Comment: Thanks Richard. I am wondering if I can stop these tickboxes from being automatically selected on existing build configurations when I add a new project.

Comment: @dan Not sure, but I would expect not (*not* building something *by default* is not a common need).